# Double integral using polar coordinate

Tags: definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

I have a problem that is related to double integral and I think that it can be solved by using polar coordinates. However, I am not sure about my answer and I need your answer to verify my own.

Calculate
$$
\iint_{D} \sqrt{x^2+y^2} dxdy
$$ 
in which D: $x^2 + y^2 \leq 2y$ and $|x| \leq y$

Comment: Post your answer up first, then we may be able to comment on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|x|\le y$, $\theta\in[\pi/4,\,3\pi/4]$. Since $r^2\le 2y=2r\sin\theta$, $r\le2\sin\theta$. The integral is$$\begin{align}\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}d\theta\int_0^{2\sin\theta}r^2dr&=\frac83\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}\sin\theta(1-\cos^2\theta)d\theta\\&=\frac89[\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta]_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}\\&=\frac{20}{9}\sqrt{2}.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** See the set $D$ in your problem...

[image]

Comment: That's right. I also see the domain D of this problem but I doubt the way I get the limits of x and y. Can you give me the limit for x and y in this problem?

Comment: Left part of set/domain $D$: $-1 \le x \le 0$, $-x \le y \le 1 + \sqrt{1-x^2}$.
Right part of set/domain $D$: $0 \le x \le 1$, $x \le y \le 1 + \sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Comment: How about using polar coordinates for this problem? I think it is better way to solve this problem. The limit for $\varphi$ and $r$ makes me confused

Comment: Sure I will help, but it is not so hard to conclude by yourself. So, I will ask you: what you can tell me for limits of variable $\varphi?$

Comment: I think that the limits for $\varphi$ is from $[\frac{\pi}{4}; \frac{3\pi}{4}]$ and the limits for $r$ is from $[0; 2sin\varphi]$

Comment: I agree about the limits for variable $\varphi$, but **not** about the limits for variable $r$. Your guess for $r$ would be true in a case that your $D$ is whole circle...

Comment: So what do you think about the limit for r?

Comment: I just figured that I made mistake in my previous comment, I was working parallel o smth else :/ So, your guesses are correct...